# Iphone Tableview reaload data how to make the new data at the top rows of the tableview

Tags: ios4

i have decler an NSMutable Array and load data from it to my tableview but here
the issue is that the new loaded data comes to the middle of tableview or at bottom
but i want that it comes at the top rows when i reload data in tableview how its possible 
if anyone can help me the i will be thankful to him/her;

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you add objects in your array. 
For example: if your NSMutableArray is named `source`, if you call

```
[source addObject:@"New row"];
```

you'll find `@"New Row"` as last row in your table, while if you call

```
[source insertObject:@"New row" atIndex:0];
```

you'll find it as first row.

Comment: actullay me add object at run time in DocumentDirectory and then through NSUserDefaults acces the directory and put the data in an NSArray so how i can do it ...?